# Error in lansat 7 image

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, remote-sensing, landsat

The actual shape of lake is like in the right corner, but in lansat 7 image that i downloaded a strip is misplaced(left image) or shifted.][how can i correct this, i have tried georeferencing already and it didn't work

[image]

Comment: To answer your question, we need to know the date & location of the imagery, and the processing performed. Personally, I expect a erroneous gap-filling done in an attempt to mitigate the problems of the SLC-off problems with Landsat 7.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen Entity ID:LE71420402016042NPA00, Acquisition Date:11-FEB-16, Path:142, Row:40, Lat=28.2380 Long=83.9956.

Answer (score 3):

What we see on this image is a good example of exactly how broken Landsat 7 is at this point.
Below is a RGB from the specific area:
[image: Landsat 7 errors]

You have faulty values and spatial errors all across the image. Overall, using this image for any sort of analysis is going to result in lots of strange things. The line seen in the question is clearly visible, and it extents across the entire image, where the values appear to be shifted about ~15 pixels to the west.

Ever since the SLC failure on Landsat 7, the satellite have been deteriorating and from this example, it appears to have reached a stage where further use is not recommended. However, I haven't reviewed additional imagery, so I can't tell if it is just this one image, or all of the newer L7 imagery being broken.

With regards to fixing it, if you really insist, you'd have to extract the strip of the image that is broken, georeference this part accordingly, and the mosaic it back into the remaining part of the image. There will still be problems, but atleast it will be marginally better than it is.